# How to hide a Flex AIR app from Taskbar?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I quickly need to know how i can hide an AIR app from the taskbar. I am using an icon in the system tray to let the user access the features in the app.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Creating windows without taskbar buttons or icons**

> On the Windows operating system,
>   windows created with the types utility
>   or lightweight do not appear on the
>   taskbar. Invisible windows do not
>   appear on the taskbar, either.
>
> Because the initial window is
>   necessarily of type, normal, in order
>   to create an application without any
>   windows appearing in the taskbar, you
>   must either close the inital window or
>   leave it invisible. To close all
>   windows in your application without
>   terminating the application, set the
>   autoExit property of the
>   NativeApplication object to false
>   before closing the last window. To
>   simply prevent the intial window from
>   ever becoming visible, add
>   false to the
>    element of the
>   application descriptor file (and do
>   not set the visible property to true
>   or call the activate() method of the
>   window).

Read more: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html